# Stop float:left from stoping my div from occupying space in another div

Tags: html, css

How can I style "a" so it occupy spaces and float left the same time?

```
<div style="background:#111">
    <div id="a" style="float:left; height:30px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is it looking right now? any fiddle or image?

Comment: @asifsid88 it looks nothing, the outter div is not showing up because it has no height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `overflow` style on the parent, without specifing a size for the parent:

```
<div style="background:#111;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="a" style="float:left; height:30px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden` causes the browsers to clear all floats at the end of the element. This includes the floats within it and therefore brings them into focus. Very handy to know!

Answer (score 1):

Insert `<div style="clear:both"></div>` right after the the "#a" div

Answer (score 1):

The floating elements doesn't influence the parent's dimensions. You need to add a *clearing element*, i.e. element with the `clear` rule set to `both`, like this:

```
<div style="background:#111">
    <div id="a" style="float:left; height:30px"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```